# MariaDB/mysql SQL query question: I want a partial sum of a column based on the group values of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view, mariadb

It's difficult (and long) for me to explain what I need, so I'll do with an example.
I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE example(
year CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
group   CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
subgroup    CHAR(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
items_1 INT(11),
set_item_1  INT(11),
items_2 INT(11),
set_item_2  INT(11),
PRIMARY KEY (year,group,subgroup)
```

);

And the next sample data:

| year | group | subgroup | items_1 | set_item_1 | items_2 | set_item_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | G001 | G001-001 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021 | G001 | G001-002 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021 | G001 | G001-003 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021 | G001 | G001-004 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021 | G001 | G001-005 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021 | G002 | G002-001 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 2021 | G002 | G002-002 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 2021 | G003 | G003-001 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020 | G001 | G001-001 | 9 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 2020 | G001 | G001-002 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 2020 | G001 | G001-003 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 2020 | G002 | G002-001 | 8 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020 | G002 | G002-002 | 8 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020 | G002 | G002-003 | 8 | 3 | 3 | 0 |

I want to implement a view (result_view) that returns this result for the former data:

```
SELECT * FROM result_view;
```

| year | group | sum_items_1 | sum_items_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | G001 | 8 | 5 |
| 2021 | G002 | 3 | 4 |
| 2021 | G003 | 7 | 1 |
| 2020 | G001 | 18 | 6 |
| 2020 | G002 | 8 | 6 |

```
set_item_1 = 0 means individual value of items_1 to sum 

set_item_2 = 0 means individual value of items_2 to sum 

set_item_1 > 0 means set n (all values of items_1 in the same n set are the same), we sum only one value of items_1 of set_item_1 = n 

set_item_2 > 0 means set m (all values of items_2 in the same m set are the same), we sum only one value of items_2 of set_item_2 = m
```

So the previous sum_items_1 and sum_items_2 of result_view are calculated based on the next formula:

| year | group | sum_items_1 | sum_items_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | G001 | 2 + 5 + 1 | 2 + 3 |
| 2021 | G002 | 3 | 4 |
| 2021 | G003 | 7 | 1 |
| 2020 | G001 | 9 + 5 + 4 | 2 + 4 |
| 2020 | G002 | 8 | 1 + 2 + 3 |

I have no idea what is the best way of doing this, any help will be apreciated.

I only have achive to split the problem into two queries (that would be mix), one for calculating set_items_1 = 0 and another for set_items_1 > 0 groups , but I don't know if this approach will be useful.

```
SELECT year,group,
    sum(items_1) AS sum_items_1
FROM example
WHERE set_item_1=0
group by year,group;

SELECT DISTINCT set_item_1, year, group,items_1 as sum_items_1
FROM example
WHERE set_item_1>0
group by DISTINCT set_item_1, year, group;
```

NOTE: In the last  query we should sum all items_1 values for each set_item_1 of the same year and group later.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT  `year`, `group`,
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN set_item_1 THEN items_1 ELSE 0 END)
      + SUM(CASE WHEN set_item_1 THEN 0 ELSE items_1 END) sum_items_1,
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN set_item_2 THEN items_2 ELSE 0 END)
      + SUM(CASE WHEN set_item_2 THEN 0 ELSE items_2 END) sum_items_2
FROM example
GROUP BY `year`, `group`
ORDER BY `year` DESC, `group` ASC;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=015fb64321afe1dff716d9c3e2d21aaf